# Attachments to a Purchase Requisition

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-ebs

I need to download attachments for over 300 purchase requisitions in the Oracle e-Business suite.  Instead of opening the requisitions one-by-one and then going to the "Manage Attachments" section, I would like to do this through a query, where I would enter the PR numbers and then get the attachments.  Does anybody know if this would be possible through a query in SQL developer (or Ms Access)?  If yes, which tables should I consider to design the query?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to give me.

Comment: if you have access to the database, then try the SQL Developer 'Find DB Object' and search on table and column names in the EBS schema - you might get lucky

Comment: Thanks.  Will try on Monday.

Comment: good luck, here's an animated GIF demo of the search feature https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/06/animated-gif-of-new-sql-developer-db-object-search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are stored in the FND_DOCUMENTS and information about which application entity / key it is attached to is in FND_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS - this [blog article](https://imdjkoch.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/attachment-in-oracle-application/) does a good job of describing the tables involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SQL https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-attached-documents/ as a basis and add a restriction to the req headers you need to see like this

```
fad.entity_name='REQ_HEADERS' and
fad.pk1_value in (select to_char(prha.requisition_header_id) from po_requisition_headers_all prha where ...) and
```

note that the to_char() is required to use the fnd_attached_documents_n1 index as fad.pk1_value is varchar2 whereas prha.requisition_header_id is a number

Comment: if you are not on EBS 12.2 yet and fnd_documents_long_text.long_text is still a long datatype, you also need the long_to_clob() function from here: https://www.enginatics.com/xxen_util/true